# Type vs interface for a nested array - which to use?

Tags: typescript

I want to have a nested array of `Item`s

```js
type Item = { name: string }
```

I've come across a few approaches and I'm trying the differences in them.

1. Using `type`

   ```js
   type Item = { name: string }
   type NestedArray<T> = Array<T> | Array<NestedArray<T>>;
   type Items = NestedArray<Item>;
   ```

   But with this approach it seems I can't have `Items` and a nested array of `Items` in the same array:

   ```js
   const items: Items = [
     // item, Error: Type '(Item | Item[][])[]' is not assignable to type 'Items'.
     [
       // item, Error: Type 'Item' is not assignable to type 'NestedArray<Item>'
       [
         // item, Error: Type '[Item, [any]]' is not assignable to type 'NestedArray<Item>'
         [
           item, // Works only as long as there isn't a nested array alongside item
         ]
       ]
     ]
   ]
   ```

   But at least it has normal Array functions:

   ```js
   items.map(i => i) // works
   ```
2. Using `interface`

   ```js
   interface Items { [n: number]: Item | Items }
   ```

   ```js
   const items: Items = [
     item
     [
       item
       [
         item
         [
           item, // All Works!
         ]
       ]
     ]
   ]
   ```

   **But** `interface Items` is no longer an `Array` (that has `map` etc functions)

   ```js
   items.map(i => i) // Error: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Items'.
   ```

How to get the best of both worlds?

- A deeply nested array that allows items and array of items side-by-side.
- Implements normal Array functions like map/filter etc.

Comment: I think it's probably best to declare dimensionality when you declare your variable:

```const items: Items[][][] = [[[{name:"blah"}]]];```

One of the advantages of type annotations is to prevent excessive runtime type-checking, so it makes sense to declare things this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But with this approach it seems I can't have Items and a nested array of Items in the same array

That should suggest the change needed:

```
type NestedArray<T> = Array<T | NestedArray<T>>;
```

I.e. instead of "an array of `T` or an array of `NestedArray<T>`" make "an array of (`T` or `NestedArray<T>`)".

Answer (score 2):

Just extend `Items` interface with `Array`:

```js
type Item = { name: string }


interface Items extends Array<Item | Items> { [n: number]: Item | Items }

const item = { name: 'John' }

const items: Items = [item, [item, [item, [item,],]]]

items.map(e => e) // ok

const x = items[0] //  Item | Items
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Woa69N)